# Cookies is html and javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

when a user logs in, I check if his cookie is already saved

if yes: welcome the user

if no: set a cookie for him

on running in internet explorer not google chrome, nothing happens
my html code is clear but I think the problem is in getCookie() after lots of debugging

```
<html>

<head>

<script>

function setCookie(c_name,value){
document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +escape(value);
}



function getCookie(c_name){

if (document.cookie.length>0)
{ 
    c_start=document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");

    if (c_start!=-1) 
    { 
        c_start=c_start + c_name.length+1; 
        c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";",c_start); 
            if (c_end==-1) {c_end=document.cookie.length;} 
        return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
    }

}
return ""; 
}




function checkCookie(){
username=getCookie('username');
password=getCookie('password');

if (username!="")
{ alert('Welcome again '+username+'!'); }
else  
{  
username=prompt('Please enter your name:',"");  
if (username!="")    
{setCookie('username',username);} 
}
}


</script>

</head>


<body>

<form>
    <h1 align="center">Login Page</h1>

    username:<br/>
    <input type="text" name="username"/> *  <br />  

    password: <br/>
    <input type="password" name="password"/> *<br />

    <input type="button" value="Log in" onclick="checkCookie()"/>
</form>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be the problem with "!=" --> change into !== in the function:

```
function checkCookie() {
    username = getCookie('username');
    password = getCookie('password');

    if (username !== "") {
        alert('Welcome again ' + username + '!');
    } else {
        username = prompt('Please enter your name:', "");
        if (username !== "") {
            setCookie('username', username);
        }
    }
}
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eL4euhab/)